# Test Method for callout in Future method

Tags: apex, unit-test, future, callout

I have a trigger on Account. On Account insert, I am sending a callout through future method. I am trying to write a test class for this but I am getting either of these two errors - 1) You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out and 2)  Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts, test skipped.
I do not want to use Test.isRunningTest(), I want to use mock callout. Its just that I am not getting when to insert account and when to use startTest() and stopTest() and when to send mock callout. I searched for this, but do not get the code example. Help with a code example is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The general solution to this can be found here: http://cropredysfdc.com/2014/06/18/batchable-class-test-data-callouts-how-to-test/ (it was written for batch classes but the principle is the same for @future)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is not what I am looking for. I tried and its not working.

Comment: you'll need to post the barest essence of your code and testmethod to get more assistance on SFSE